# Controlling reactivity in Shiny

Tags: r, plot, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I have a Shiny Dashboard that has 4 tabs that display 4 different plots.  The last plot is a 3 D Plotly plot.  It is parameter driven which are provided by two input text controls and one select box.  It works fine, but it is quite slow.

Therefore, I am trying to control its reactivity by putting an submitButton next to the parameter controls so that it is redrawn only when the user clicks the submitButton.  Trouble is: it affects the other three plots as well.  Is there a way to control the reactivity so that it only affects the desired plot?

Comment: Use an `observeEvent()` to observe the button press, and `isolate()` the input controls so that the plot doesn't react to them. Provide example code and we can help further.